# NVD3 - Graph taking modified JSON data not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am working with D3 & NVD3 to create graphs from data pulled from an API. The data is returned in the following format:

```
[ 
  {
"id": 1,
"timestamp": "2014-01-01T02:05:54",
"value": 10000,
"ctclip_id": 1
 },

 {
"id": 1,
"timestamp": "2015-01-01T02:05:54",
"value": 12000,
"ctclip_id": 1
 },

 {
"id": 1,
"timestamp": "2016-01-01T02:05:54",
"value": 9000,
"ctclip_id": 1
 },

 {
"id": 2,
"timestamp": "2015-01-01T02:05:54",
"value": 4500,
"ctclip_id": 1
 },

{
"id": 3,
"timestamp": "2016-01-01T02:05:54",
"value": 100,
"ctclip_id": 2
 },

 {
"id": 4,
"timestamp": "2017-01-01T02:05:54",
"value": 200,
"ctclip_id": 2
 }
```

]

I have used the D3.nest feature and some hardcoding:

```
var newData = d3.nest()
.key(function(d,i){ return d.id; })
.entries(data);

newData[0]['bar']=true;
newData[1]['bar']=true;
newData[2]['bar']=true;
newData[3]['bar']=true;
```

which changes the JSON format to:

```
[
{
"key":"1",
"values":
[
    {"id":1,"timestamp":"2014-01-01T02:05:54","value":10000,"ctclip_id":1},
    {"id":1,"timestamp":"2015-01-01T02:05:54","value":12000,"ctclip_id":1},
    {"id":1,"timestamp":"2016-01-01T02:05:54","value":9000,"ctclip_id":1}
],
"bar":true},

{
"key":"2",
"values":
[
    {"id":2,"timestamp":"2015-01-01T02:05:54","value":4500,"ctclip_id":1}
],
"bar":true},

{
"key":"3",
"values":
[
    {"id":3,"timestamp":"2016-01-01T02:05:54","value":100,"ctclip_id":2}
],
"bar":true
},
{
"key":"4",
"values":
[
    {"id":4,"timestamp":"2017-01-01T02:05:54","value":200,"ctclip_id":2}
],
"bar":true}
```

]

I am trying to graph the data but the bars for ID 1 are overlapping each other. Bar data for other IDs can only be seen by hiding ID 1 (or other IDs). Here is a JSFiddle of what I'm having trouble with: **http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/1/**

I'm also experiencing difficulty with the timestamp on the Y Axis but am hoping that when I get the bars displaying separately this issue will be fixed (or easy to fix).

Any help is appreciated! Sorry for the long post!

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**
Thanks to @ameliabr I found a solution. I have a completed JSFiddle here if anyone is having the same problem - http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/7/ . I used:

```
var newData = d3.nest()
.key(function(d,i){ return d.id; })
.entries(data);

newData[0]['bar']=true;

var newData2 = d3.nest()
.key(function(d,i){ return d.id; })
.entries(data2);
```

to format the JSON data to be compatible with D3. Then the one line that fixed it all was:
`newData.push(newData2[0]);`

Comment: You're never turning your timestamp strings into date objects.  Create an appropriate [time format parsing function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse), and then use it in your x-accessor function on the chart object: `chart.x(function(d){return timestampFormat.parse(d.timestamp);})`

Comment: By the way, is there a reason you're using the line+bar graph instead of the discrete bar or grouped bar graphs?

Comment: I missed that, thanks. I have a function at the end of the code to convert the timestamp. I updated this line:
    `.x(function(d,i) { return d.timestamp })`
to:
    `.x(function(d){return (date1.setISO8601(d.timestamp));})`
following your advice but it's still not displaying correctly.

Yes, I am graphing two sets of data against each other, one being displayed in bar format and the other being displayed as simple dots (those shown in line, using CSS to take out the line).

Here's an updated JSFiddle - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/2/)

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. By changing to this: `.x(function(d,i){return i})` the bars are now spaced correctly. Now I just need to fix the issue with displaying data from different IDs. **Updated JSFiddle - [http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/3/) **

Comment: Also I need to somehow fix this        `chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        var date0 = new Date();
       return d3.time.format('%x')(date0.setISO8601(newData[0].values[0].timestamp));` so that I can access all timestamps. However, I cannot use `newData[d].values[d].timestamp` without getting an error, due to my data format (which is slightly different from the default as shown in original question above).

Comment: On the date format, the internal parser should be able to handle your timestamps (and if not, a d3 time formatter would!).  Here's your fiddle with properly formatted date values on the x axis:http://jsfiddle.net/7N4Ma/4/.  
However, the bars still overlap because the bar+line graph isn't designed to show multiple bars side-by-side; it's only designed to have one bar for each x value.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I think we are just going to be graphing data from one ID at a time so it's not a problem. Graph with a small bit more data - [http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/5/).

Comment: One more thing, I want to graph another set of data (from the API) against the bars. The data will be displayed as dots (as part of the line graph). What's the most efficient way to do that? _I did it simply by duplicating the code and making a few tweaks and then using `<div id='chart'><div id='chart1'><svg style='height:500px'></svg>`  to display both the charts._ Is there an easier way?

Comment: The whole idea of the bar+line graph is it can do both in one chart.  And there doesn't seem to be any problem with doing multiple series of *lines*.  The default style appears to be to draw the scatterplot and no line, so this is pretty much what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/7N4Ma/6/.

Comment: That said, if you do want side-by-side graphs with the same chart type but different data, you need to create a d3 selector that will grab both SVG, and then assign the appropriate data to each with a [d3 data join](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) before calling the chart function.  I.e., if your structure is `<div id="chart"><svg id="chart1"></svg><svg id="chart2"></svg></div>`, then your chart call is: `d3.selectAll('#chart svg').data([data1, data2]).call(chart);`

Comment: That example on JSFiddle looks great! That is almost exactly what I want! I will be using separate data from the original set though. The second set of data will also be from the API and will need to be reformatted. It will be in the same format and may have the same ID so I can't filter by ID. Any idea how I could incorporate the second set of data?

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't see your second comment. I'm looking at this now.

Comment: @AmeliaBR I'm currently using `d3.json("data.json",function(error,data2) {` to read in data from JSON files, which will soon be replaced by an API call. What would be the best way to join two sets of separate data into one data set that would work with the linePlusBarChart?

Comment: NVD3 expects you to pass data for each chart that is an array of data series (where each series contains an array of values).  So something like `data.push(data2[0])` would work if your individual JSON files are already each formatted for NVD3.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! All I was missing was the [0].

Comment: Great!  P.S.  You can post your solution as an answer, so that this question doesn't show up on the unanswered questions list.

Comment: I can't select an answer, I don't think I have enough rep yet.

Comment: You can't select a comment as an answer, you need to re-write it below.  (New users have to [wait 8 hours before answering their own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but you're well past that now!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a completed JSFiddle here if anyone is having the same problem - http://jsfiddle.net/emjaycub/7N4Ma/7/ . I used:

```
var newData = d3.nest()
.key(function(d,i){ return d.id; })
.entries(data);

newData[0]['bar']=true;

var newData2 = d3.nest()
.key(function(d,i){ return d.id; })
.entries(data2);
```

to format the JSON data to be compatible with D3. Then the one line that fixed it all was:

```
newData.push(newData2[0]);
```

Here's a Pastebin of all of the code: http://pastebin.com/mEPcrFbB